# inserting row in sqlite table using ORM returns KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I'm trying to insert data in sqlite table, but i get an error

this is the way I created the table

```
            [SQLite.Table("table_sessions")]
            public class table_sessions
            {
                            [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
                            public int? id { get; set; }

                            public string sessionid { get; set; }

                            public DateTime created { get; set; }

            }
```

conn is SQLiteConnection object

```
            conn.CreateTable<table_sessions>();
```

then I try to insert data like this

```
                using (var conn = sql.conn())
                {
                    conn.Insert(new table_sessions()
                    {
                        sessionid = someVariable,
                        created = DateTime.Now,
                    });
                }
```

It gives me this error

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   Blockquote

I tried to supply the id=-1 , id=1, and I still get the same error. 
Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message may refer to that you do not have any primary keys. Since I see you have written the primary key for the id, I think you are not using the right attributes.

See the article provided by Xamarin, it will be useful. I started using it on my own and succeeded.

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/#Recipe

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am not Sure, Why it is Marked as nullable, try making it as an integer

```
public int? id { get; set; } // This is a nullable field. 
public int id { get; set; }
```

I would suggest have an Entity Base

```
public class EntityBase 
{
  [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
  public int? id { get; set; }
}

[SQLite.Table("table_sessions")]    
public class table_sessions : EntityBase 
{
    public string sessionid { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; 
}
```